# Python reading xml

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie on Python programming. I have requirement where I need to read the xml structure and build the new soap request xml by adding namespace like here is the example what I have

Below XML which i get from other system:

```
<foo>
   <bar>
      <type foobar="1"/>
      <type foobar="2"/>
   </bar>
</foo>
```

I want final result like below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soa:foo xmlns:soa="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
   <soa:bar>
      <soa:type foobar="1"/>
      <soa:type foobar="2"/>
   </soa:bar>
</soa:foo>
```

I tried to look in python [document](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents) but not able to find

Comment: I updated the code formatting and tried to fix the output. Please take a look and make sure that's what you really want. Have you looked at ElementTree or lxml?

Comment: what documentation do you mean? Show link in question (not in comment). What module do you use - standard [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/markup.html), or external `lxml`, `Beautifulsoup`, or other.

Comment: @furas I am trying to find the example in Python which read the xml and provide above desired output.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use lxml to iterate over all of the elements and add the namespace uri to the `.tag` property.

You can use `register_namespace()` to bind the uri to the desired prefix.

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

etree.register_namespace("soa", "https://www.w3schools.com/furniture")

for elem in tree.iter():
    elem.tag = f"{{https://www.w3schools.com/furniture}}{elem.tag}"

print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Printed output...

```xml
<soa:foo xmlns:soa="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
   <soa:bar>
      <soa:type foobar="1"/>
      <soa:type foobar="2"/>
   </soa:bar>
</soa:foo>
```